# Bootstrap's SCSS fails to compile - always getting "`unit($number)` must be a number" error

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, sass, gulp

I want to use Bootstaps grids locally in my project.

I am compiling SCSS with Gulp. I can confirm this works fine - I am able to compile my own scss files.

However, when I add any Bootstrap .scss file I get the error:

> assets\scss\bootstrap_scss_functions.scss Error: argument `$number`
> of `unit($number)` must be a number

This occurrs both with Bootstrap 4.5.3 and 5.0 Alpha.

My app.scss file looks like:

```
@import 'bootstrap_scss/_functions';
@import 'bootstrap_scss/_variables';
@import 'bootstrap_scss/_mixins';

@import 'bootstrap_scss/bootstrap-reboot';
@import 'bootstrap_scss/bootstrap-grid';
```

I've also tried the NPM version of Bootstrap, but get the same results.

Would anyone know what I should be doin?

Comment: Bootstrap 4.5.3 **doesn't define** any `$number` variable (not sure about other versions), so it has to be your custom variable. Not sure how your `bootstrap_scss_functions.scss` looks but just to be sure, have you actually defined `$number` ?

Comment: @Fahmi no I havent defined that. Looking at the file the erroneous line is `@if $prev-num == null or unit($num) == "%" or unit($prev-num) == "%" {`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the source code of [_functions.scss](https://github.com/crissdev/bootstrap-scss/blob/master/_functions.scss) and [_variables.scss](https://github.com/crissdev/bootstrap-scss/blob/master/_variables.scss) looks like you are overriding either `$container-max-widths` and/or `$grid-breakpoints` variable(s).

Make sure both variables have numeric value for the value in map. Default values are:

```
$grid-breakpoints: (
  xs: 0,
  sm: 576px,
  md: 768px,
  lg: 992px,
  xl: 1200px
) !default;

$container-max-widths: (
  sm: 540px,
  md: 720px,
  lg: 960px,
  xl: 1140px
) !default;
```